# distance between QStrings of several words Qt c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, qt, comparison, qstring

I'm currently trying to compare two strings of several words. I know it's possible to get the distance between two strings with the levenstein algorithm. It's working well. But how can I get the distance between several words?

I'm programming an application who makes researches on TMDB from movies titles and I'm getting several titles as results. I need to associate title results with my movie title. I got the idea to compare words one by one and to keep the best results but I don't think it's the best way to do it.

I need it to consider spelling mistakes (star wars/star wards), numbers (matrix 1, matrix 2, etc...), more words (matrix 2 - Reloaded/Matrix Reloaded).

Thank you for your help. I'm using C++ Qt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For comparing natural language one of the most successful model is "bag of words": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model, this is widely used with success in many spam filtering tools. 
There are of course c++ implementations, a famous one is inside openCV, but if I were you I would try to write my own variation including the levenstein algorithm.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at it. I'm thinking like you, I'll have to write my own variation. I'll probably make sevral tries on my movies until I get the algorithm working. But I was wondering it already exists ^^.